# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel with a third party WCF service in IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, x509certificate, x509

I am trying to consume a third party WCF service, that requires X.509 Certificate to be configured in client side. I am provided with a .p12 file and a passphrase. I installed it in LocalComputer. I configured in my web forms application the store name (My when I installed in personal store, and Root when I did it in TCA). When I tried to make a request it was aborted with the above error. This is already present.

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
</security>
```

Should I do anything extra in IIS where my web forms app is hosted or should I ask the third party for any more files? Is there any steps online describing what a client needs to do in IIS for X.509 cert auth?

The above setup works well in when I use Visual Studio Internal Server by clicking Google Chrome. But the error is when it is published in IIS.

UPDATE:
I did [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/131046/how-to-grant-iis-7-5-access-to-a-certificate-in-certificate-store) and it works properly in windows server 2008. In windows 7 it is not working still. In windows 7 even the internal visual studio server is not working properly to make this request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that the channel was not TLS1.2. And setting it code like any other answer in other posts suggests will work. If that is not an option, you have to make sure you make request with TLS1.2 by editing in reg edit.

[This](https://support.quovadisglobal.com/kb/a433/how-to-enable-tls-1_2-on-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx) should help for setting it up in reg edit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you need to install the client certificate into `CurrentUser\My` certificate store, not `LocalMachine`. Standard users don't have access to certificates installed in LocalMachine store.

**Update**

> The above setup works well in when I use Visual Studio Internal Server by clicking Google Chrome. But the error is when it is published in IIS.

web site in IIS runs under application pool security context. You must install the certificate into Personal store of the account used by application pool. When you run web application in Visual Studion debugger, it runs under your user account and your user account obviously has this certificate in personal store. The error suggests that the certificate is not installed in application pool's personal store.

Comment: What I have currently works perfectly in Windows Server 2008. But not in Windows 7. Probably need to add that in question. I will try in CurrentUser and let you know.

Comment: `Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'CurrentUser', FindType 'FindByIssuerName', FindValue 'ws.docvelocity4.net'.` I am getting this error. I ensured it is present in current user and also IIS. Also figured that it is not the OS that is causing, it is the IIS vs VS internal server that is the problem

Comment: Error message suggests that you indeed need to install the certificate to current user store.

Comment: I think you missed the part where I mentioned I ensured it is installed

Comment: Where? I only see this: `I installed it in LocalComputer`. Also, make sure if certificate meets search criteria.

Comment: What is search criteria? I can do Find by Issuer ID in MMC in Current User Store

Comment: What you are saying makes sense. Can you tell me what and where I need to go. I m pretty new. Will I find it in Service Account? What should be the store location and store name in that case?

Comment: There are two options: make interactive logon with service account (if possible), or implement a small API that would accept the certificate (from file, for example) and install it into `CurrentUser\My` store. API must be executed under service account.